# How does the Dragon Tattoo damage work?

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

> The dragon is a fearsome tattoo, and contains frightening power waiting to be unleashed. As a Complex Action, you may breathe fire in a cone, equal to ten feet plus your School Rank in length, and five feet wide at the end. This fire deals damage to all in its area of effect, with a DR equal your Fire Ring. You take damage equal to your Fire Ring upon each use.

How does the Dragon Tattoo's damage work mechanically? Do you roll your fire ring in kept dice (IE: 3k3) against each enemy in the cone individually? Do you roll once and apply the damage to all of them? Is it not rolled (IE: each enemy takes 3 damage)? And would you take 3 damage or 3k3?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I have yet to find any specific RAW source, but I see the Dragon Tattoo almost identical in function to the Air 1 spell "Tempest of Air" in that **each target has damage rolled individually**.  Even though spells aren't terribly specific either, the wording comes down to "each target takes damage" as opposed to "deal X damage to each target"  Since the damage is variable, it should be rolled per person because of any number of reasons whether reasonable, abstract, or just plain plot driven ("Oh... I rolled 6 Wounds...").

Answer (score 2):

Damage Rating for spells is usually in the form of XkX, where X is defined by the spell description (in this case, it's equal to the Fire ring of the user), whenever damage is not in this form, it's detailed on its description.

So, as per the description, the damage would be (Fire Ring)k(Fire Ring), in your case 3k3.
The damage applied to the user is **equal** to his Fire Ring, so, if he has Fire 3, he will take 3 damage.

What is left is to determine if it's just one roll or multiple rolls, one per target.
Since source material doesn't enter into details here, i tend to specify that is one roll for all targets as it saves me a lot of rolls when players are facing multiple weaker opponents.